# MVC5 / C# - Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to figure out what's causing a `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` error from this code:

```
var query = "SELECT Id, UserName, List_Order, LoggedIn " + 
            "FROM AspNetUsers" +
            "WHERE LoggedIn = 1" + 
            "ORDER BY List_Order ASC";

var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   
conn.Open();
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var n = 0;
while(rdr.Read())
{
    if (Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]) != null)
    {
        ViewBag.speakers[n] = new string[4] {
            Convert.ToString(rdr["Id"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["List_Order"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["LoggedIn"]) 
        };

        //Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot 
        //perform runtime binding on a null reference
        n++;
    }
}
```

The `n++` increment seems to be the cause of this error and I don't understand why.

Updated code to reflect possible solutions. However, the error still remains.

Tried this with the same result:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]))) {
        List<string> speakers = new List<string>();
        speakers.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["Id"]));
        speakers.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]));
        speakers.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["List_Order"]));
        speakers.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["LoggedIn"]));

        ViewBag.speakers[n] = speakers;
        n++;
}
```

Comment: Check out [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235162/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference-empty-excel-cells)

Comment: @LuisLavieri I updated the code and the error still shows up.

Comment: Did you also update the `if`? now it should be: `if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"])))`

Comment: @LuisLavieri Yes I did change it to that but no change.

Comment: I see that you are trying to access the `ViewBag` as an array. Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26018835/1188208) from a different post.

Comment: @LuisLavieri Updated the code with the help of your comment, but still getting the same result.

Comment: Can you also show the view where ViewBag.speakers is used?

Comment: What kind of `ViewBag.speakers` value given after `Read` method executed (please use debugger to see it)? I suspected this error is more than just `ToString` conversion, it may occurred on `SqlDataReader` when iterating results to `ViewBag` array.

Comment: Have you checked the query result. Its syntax doesn't look right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

Consider this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   int n = 0;
   ViewBag.speakers[n] = 5;
   return View();
}
```

This simplified piece of code throws `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference` since speakers is not defined (null reference).

You can fix it by defining `speakers` in the *dynamic* ViewBag before the loop:

```
ViewBag.speakers = new List<string>();
```

The second issue:

```
ViewBag.speakers[n] = speakers;
```

speakers in your code is a List, you might want to define `ViewBag.speakers` as a `List<List<string>>` and call `.Add(speakers)` instead of accessing using an index (you might get *index was out of range*)

Answer (score 2):

Calling the `.ToString()` method on a null column value can result in the `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`. Use `Convert.ToString()` instead; it will return an empty string if you attempt to convert a `null` value and won't require additional code for `null` checking.

Comment: Thats a nice trick to remember. I'd have gone all in with `potentiallyNull?.ToString() ?? string.Empty`

Comment: I tried the `Convert.ToString` methods but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Daniel you have instantiated `speakers` somewhere right?

Comment: @Daniel sorry - I just saw the below example you posted.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` is a dynamic object and when you try to do assignments to its properties, the null check will happen in runtime. You get this error because `ViewBag.speakers` is either null, or it throws an exception while trying to access its `nth` slot with indexer (maybe its size is less than `n`, or it doesn't define an indexer at all). You should initialize `ViewBag.speakers` before adding elements to it.

```
var query = "SELECT Id, UserName, List_Order, LoggedIn " + 
            "FROM AspNetUsers" +
            "WHERE LoggedIn = 1" + 
            "ORDER BY List_Order ASC";

var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   
conn.Open();
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ViewBag.speakers = new List<string[]>();
while(rdr.Read())
{
    if (Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]) != null)
    {
        var speakers = new string[4] {
            Convert.ToString(rdr["Id"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["UserName"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["List_Order"]),
            Convert.ToString(rdr["LoggedIn"]) 
        };
        ViewBag.speakers.Add(speakers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems originated from usage of `Read` method after `ExecuteReader`, which gives null reference on dynamic object `ViewBag.speakers` at certain point that enough to throw runtime binding exception on view side.

Using `DataTable.Load` and simple for-loop to iterate `DataTable` contents, I modified **Gökhan Kurt**'s answer to this one:

```
var query = "SELECT Id, UserName, List_Order, LoggedIn " + 
            "FROM AspNetUsers" +
            "WHERE LoggedIn = 1" + 
            "ORDER BY List_Order ASC";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        ViewBag.speakers = new List<string[]>();
        var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(rdr);

        for (int n = 0; n < dt.Rows.Count; n++)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[n]["UserName"])))
            {
                // speakers returns String[4] array instead of null value
                var speakers = new String[4] {
                    Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[n]["Id"]),
                    Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[n]["UserName"]),
                    Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[n]["List_Order"]),
                    Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[n]["LoggedIn"])
                };

                ViewBag.speakers.Add(speakers);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

NB: `SqlDataReader.Read()` is forward-only, it will returns `false` after last row has reached. The `ViewBag.speakers` assigned to null reference if the `DataReader.Read` method returns false, thus while loop is not executed. Using `DataTable.Load` method keeps returned data from `ExecuteReader` even after `SqlDataReader` is closed or reached last row.

Secondly, you may look at [reader.Read() only read once even when there are multiple rows to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475901/reader-read-only-read-once-even-when-there-are-multiple-rows-to-read) problem, but IMHO it seems only work when the row length is already known or fixed size. Since it is impossible to use `SqlDataReader.RecordsAffected` before the data reader is closed, you need another way to get row count from `SqlDataReader`.

References:

[Populate data table from data reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961938/populate-data-table-from-data-reader)

[SqlDataReader.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SqlDataReader.RecordsAffected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.recordsaffected(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataTable.Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx)